# mock method in .net

Tags: .net, mocking

I am using mock testing. I want to simply ask what mock.record() and mock.playback() do.
If any simple eexample will be provided it will be highly appreciated...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In "record" you can record an action, for example the executing of a stored procedure or the retrieving of a records from the database and putting them in a datatable In "playback" the recored action is played back when that piece of code gets hit.

Rhinomocks example

```
    [Test]
    public void GetHtmlTest()
    {
        var mocks = new MockRepository();
        var dal = mocks.StrictMock<DataAccess>();
        var mockdatatable = new DataTable();

        using (mocks.Record())
        {
            Expect.Call(dal.GetDataTableFromDatabase("", null)).Return(mockdatatable ).IgnoreArguments().Repeat.Any();
            Expect.Call(dal.ExecuteUsingStoredProcedure("", null)).Return(true).IgnoreArguments().Repeat.Any();
        }

        using (mocks.Playback())
        {
            new SomeText(dal);
            var result = SomeText.GetHtml("test","","");
            Assert.AreEqual(result, string.Empty);
        }


    }
```

Instead of doing a real database call in SomeText.GetHtml. The mockdatatable is returned by the method.